# ggplot2 axis formatting using n.breaks and labels

Tags: ggplot2, scale, graph-visualization

While creating a graph with ggplot2, I'm having trouble to format the x-axis which are dates that show as numerical values. I want to use 'n.breaks' in 'scale_x_continuous'. From the documentation, I see that the 'labels' argument can be "A function that takes the breaks as input and returns labels as output.". How do I access those breaks and pass them in a formatting function to get my labels? Here's a sample of my code:

```
ggplot(data = aggregatedCovidData) +
   geom_line(aes(x = date, y = newCases/1000)) +
   labs(title = "COVID-19 daily new cases (000's) timeline",
        x = NULL,
        y = NULL) +
   scale_x_continuous(
      n.breaks = 9
      # ,labels = as_date()
   )
```

If you need more than a sample of code, I've uploaded
[my data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/08ue3rt73apv70v/aggregatedCovidData.rds?dl=0) to dropbox as well as [my code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqj98v11tqftth6/Reprex.R?dl=0).

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

As requested by chemdork123, I've added a sample of my data here. I'll keep the sample code as it is, because the rest of it is not relevant to the problem.

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(18262, 18263, 18264, 18265, 
18266, 18267, 18268, 18269, 18270, 18271, 18272, 18273, 18274, 
18275, 18276, 18277, 18278, 18279, 18280, 18281, 18282, 18283, 
18284, 18285, 18286, 18287, 18288, 18289, 18290, 18291, 18292, 
18293, 18294, 18295, 18296, 18297, 18298, 18299, 18300, 18301, 
18302, 18303, 18304, 18305, 18306, 18307, 18308, 18309, 18310, 
18311, 18312, 18313, 18314, 18315, 18316, 18317, 18318, 18319, 
18320, 18321, 18322, 18323, 18324, 18325, 18326, 18327, 18328, 
18329, 18330, 18331, 18332, 18333, 18334, 18335, 18336, 18337, 
18338, 18339, 18340, 18341, 18342, 18343, 18344, 18345, 18346, 
18347, 18348, 18349, 18350, 18351, 18352, 18353, 18354, 18355, 
18356, 18357, 18358, 18359, 18360, 18361), class = "Date"), newCases = 
c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
392, 1146, 1973, 2736, 3237, 10608, 2358, 8272, 6771, 8450, 18998, 
12402, 16045, 14980, 12648, 14256, 10929, 12120, 10290, 8170, 
1592, 60608, 26026, 8439, 8592, 7942, 7352, 1842, 2214, 2533, 
7086, 1499, 2346, 3519, 4038, 5686, 5836, 7924, 10219, 8410, 
11006, 10077, 12584, 17213, 18388, 18116, 19643, 22059, 35284, 
26473, 67557, 51791, 52483, 69351, 73988, 90618, 125198, 141006, 
147124, 157929, 192913, 184684, 230876, 282471, 290149, 310396, 
253111, 287410, 337570, 361260, 359891, 367883, 241710, 300750, 
315166, 293112, 359142, 374295)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = 
c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi OP - can you please post your data and code here instead of linking via dropbox?  Code should be pasted and formatted as code for readability and the data can most easily be posted as code as well.  Try `dput(aggregatedCovidData)` and copy/paste the output here as code.  If that's too much to post, then you can provide a sample of that dataset via `sample()` or `head()` functions with a reasonable number of observations that can reproduce the problem in your question.

Comment: If you x-variable is a date, you might instead be interested in `scale_x_date()`, where you can supply a formatting string to `date_labels`.

Comment: @teunbrand Thx I didn't know about `scale_x_date()` and it works like a charm in my case. I'm still curious as to how to use `labels` and `n.breaks` in `scale_x_continuous()` though.

Comment: The `n.breaks` seems to be used correctly, for the formatting function you can do `labels = function(x) {paste0(x, "_formatted")}` or something of the sort.

Comment: Thank you @teunbrand! you thought me a lot my friend :)